# sql server output parameters ado.net

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("LossID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output)
.....
Dim LossID as integer

lossID = cmd.Parameters("@LossID").Value
```

When I add my output parameter to my command object, I am receiving a

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type
>   objects, not Boolean objects.

How do I correctly place my return value into the `lossID` integer? thank you very much

Comment: Your definition uses `LossID` and when you try to access your parameters collection, you use `@LossID` - I think you should consistently use the notation with the leading at (`@`) sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the assignment of the Direction property from the adding of the parameter to the parameters collection.

```
param = New SqlParameter("LossID", SqlDbType.Int)
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
```

Comment: Seems wierd, why cant i one line it?

Comment: Because the type of `New SqlParameter("LossID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output` is a `Boolean`, not a `SqlParameter` while `cmd.Parameters.Add(.)` needs to be given an object of type `SqlParameter`.